# How to use loan-fixture method with AsyncFeatureSpec?

Tags: scala, scalatest, fixtures

How can I use loan-fixture method with AsyncFeatureSpec? 
I have tried as the following:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.testkit._
import com.sweetsoft._
import org.scalatest._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class SapOnlineKafkaOnlineSpec extends fixture.AsyncFeatureSpec with Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen
  with BeforeAndAfter
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  private val listener1 = TestProbe()
  private val detector = system.actorOf(DetectorSupervisor.props)

  def withKafkaAndSap(testCode: (ActorRef) => Any) {



  }


  feature("Detect Kafka and SAP availability") {
    info("As a technical user, I want to be notified in real time, if Kafka and SAP is up and running or not.")
    scenario("SAP and Kafka are available") in withKafkaAndSap { (listener) =>
      Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
      detector ! AddNewListener(listener1.ref)
      When("I am receive the state message")
      val res1 = listener1.expectMsgPF[Assertion](6.second) _
      Then("it should contain `SAP and Kafka are online`")
      res1 {
        case status: ServerStatus =>
          status.health should be(ServersOnline)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know, how to inject the loan method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
class SapOnlineKafkaOnlineSpec extends AsyncFeatureSpec with Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen
  with BeforeAndAfter
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  def withKafkaAndSap(testCode: ActorRef => Future[Assertion]) = {
    val actor = ...
    testCode(actor)
  }

  feature("Detect Kafka and SAP availability") {
    info("As a technical user, I want to be notified in real time, if Kafka and SAP is up and running or not.")
    scenario("SAP and Kafka are available") {
      withKafkaAndSap { listner =>
        Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
        When("I am receive the state message")
        Then("it should contain `SAP and Kafka are online`")
        succeed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the loan fixture parameter type should be

```
testCode: ActorRef => Future[Assertion]
```

instead of `ActorRef => Any`, and we extend just `AsyncFeatureSpec` instead of `fixture.AsyncFeatureSpec`

Comment: I've got `type mismatch`, it says `found  : Unit`  `required: scala.concurrent.Future[org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion]`

Comment: You probably missed the equals `=` before opening brace `{`,  right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Why do I need the equal sign?

Comment: Otherwise it becomes procedure syntax which is likely to be removed from future Scala: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/procedure-syntax.html